# Altium Designer 15.1: "From-To"s are only displayed when moving component

Tags: altium

I am having an issue in Altium Designer 15.1 where the "From-To"s are only shown when I'm moving the component. I prefer them to be visible all the time. I have gone into the layer stack dialog, clicked the Show/Hide tab, clicked "From To Settings", and ensured "Show From Tos" is set to "Automatic". I have also tried setting it to "Always", but they still do not appear. The connections are clearly still made, though, because when I hover over a pad in the net, all other pads in the same net are highlighted.

Are there any other settings that would hide "From-To"s, even when the display settings are set to "show"?

Comment: In the layer color dialog, make sure "Default net color" in the lower right area is checked off as visible. (commenting from memory, so I might have the name wrong).

Comment: @ThePhoton It is indeed checked: http://s30.postimg.org/jz3vum1gx/2015_09_09_12_12_17_View_Configurations.png

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, no. From here, my thoughts go to things like graphics card compatibility or driver issues...

Comment: My computer did an automatic chkdsk last week and deleted some damaged files. I didn't notice an issue until within the past couple of days. I'm wondering if they are related. I have a question out to Altium tech support, but I may just have to re-install the software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got a response from Altium tech support. I'm not sure why it happened in the first place, but the solution is very simple. Use the "N-S-A" shortcut ("Netlist"-->"Show Connections"-->"All"). All From-Tos appear and display as expected.